# Grafico de líneas generado por Pygal muestra relleno (polígono) al mostrarlo en un QSvgWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, svg

Estoy tratando de generar un gráfico de línea en Pygal pero al ingresar los valores, me genera un relleno indeseado.

Toda la zona roja, se supone que debería de verse unicamente la linea con los puntos de referencia, como la linea azul

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el código completo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic, QtSvg
import pygal
from pygal.style import Style

class PygalClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("pygal.ui",self)

        custom_style = Style(
            background='white',
            plot_background='white',
            colors=('#003d4f', 'red'),

        )

        grafico = QtSvg.QSvgWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(grafico)

        visual = pygal.Line(style=custom_style)
        visual.x_labels = ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"]
        visual.x_label_rotation=50
        visual.add("Meta", [10,20,30,40,50])
        visual.add("Actual", [15,25,35,45,43,None])
        data = visual.render()
        grafico.load(data)

app = QApplication([])
pc = PygalClass()
pc.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema aparentemente está solo en Qt,  PyGal por defecto no genera el relleno a no ser que se le indique usando el parámetro `fill=True`. De hecho el svg es renderizado sin problemas por Inkscape.

La [documentación de Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/svgrendering.html#rendering-svg-files) puede darnos una pista:

> Qt admite las funciones estáticas de SVG 1.2 Tiny. Los **scripts ECMA y la manipulación DOM** no son actualmente soportados.

Estas limitaciones hacen que `QtSvg` no soporte todas las características usadas por PyGal y esta es una de ellas.

Se me ocurren un par de opciones:

- Usar  [`render_to_png`](http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/output.html#png)  para renderizar el svg y generar una imagen png, que puede ser mostrada sin problemas  en la interfaz:

  ```
  import io
  import sys

  import pygal
  from pygal.style import Style

  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel
  from PyQt5 import uic
  from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap



  class PygalClass(QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()

          custom_style = Style(
              background='white',
              plot_background='white',
              colors=('#003d4f', 'red'),
          )

          grafico = QLabel()
          self.setCentralWidget(grafico)

          visual = pygal.Line(style=custom_style)
          visual.x_labels = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", 
                             "Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre",
                             "Noviembre","Diciembre"]
          visual.x_label_rotation=50
          visual.add("Meta", [10,20,30,40,50])
          visual.add("Actual", [15,25,35,45,43,None])

          pix = QPixmap()
          with io.BytesIO() as f:
             visual.render_to_png(f)
             pix.loadFromData(f.getvalue())

          grafico.setPixmap(pix)


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      app = QApplication(sys.argv)
      pc = PygalClass()
      pc.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
  ```
- Usar [`render_data_uri`](http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/output.html#base-64-data-uri) y aprovechar `QtWebEngineWidgets` (`QWebEngineView`) para mostrar la imagen. Posiblemente sea la opción que mejores resultados ofrece:

  ```
  import sys

  import pygal
  from pygal.style import Style 
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
  from PyQt5 import uic
  from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
  from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView



  class PygalClass(QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()

          custom_style = Style(
              background='white',
              plot_background='white',
              colors=('#003d4f', 'red'),
          )

          grafico = QWebEngineView()
          self.setCentralWidget(grafico)

          visual = pygal.Line(style=custom_style)
          visual.x_labels = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", 
                             "Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre",
                             "Noviembre","Diciembre"]
          visual.x_label_rotation=50
          visual.add("Meta", [10,20,30,40,50])
          visual.add("Actual", [15,25,35,45,43,None])
          data = visual.render_data_uri()
          grafico.setUrl(QUrl(data))


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      app = QApplication(sys.argv)
      pc = PygalClass()
      pc.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
  ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]